# How to create a clickable button from text

Tags: php, html

My goal here is to create a clickable button from text. I want to take an image - a rounded button, and combine it with text. I know there's a super easy way to do this in HTML5, but I'm not certain I'm willing to just not support older browsers.

Is there a way to take the image of a rounded button, take text from elsewhere (in this case, a database), and make the entire thing clickable?

Note, this would be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

There's all sorts of ways to do this, for example you could create a div with two elements in it, one the image and the other the text, and load both dynamically, you could make the div background the image and content the text, you could generate the entire thing on the server side and return the complete image, etc.

oh and you can also create a button element with text ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to simply generate the button image through a PHP graphical library. This way, your server handle image and text, and you do not have to worry about the browser (though you might want to check that the size of your button doesn't break your site layout, if it's really dynamical).